# How to rename multiple files in linux and store the old file names with the new file name in a text file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am a novice Linux user. I have 892 .pdb files, I want to rename all of them in a sequential order as L1,L2,L3,L4...........,L892. And then I want a text file which contains the old names assigned to new names ( i.e L1,L2,L3). Please help me with this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you ordering the files?  What are the current names?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
for f in *.pdb; do
        : $((i += 1))
        mv "$f"  L"$i" && echo "$f --> L$i"
done > filelist
```

Note that you probably want to move the files into a different directory, as that will make it easier to recover if an error occurs midway through.  Also be wary that this will overwrite any existing files and potentially cause a big mess.  It's not idempotent (you can't run it twice).  You would probably be better off not doing the move at all and instead do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
mkdir -p newfiles
for f in *.pdb; do
        ln "$f" newfiles/L"$((++i))" && printf "%s\0%s\0" "$f" "L$i"
done > filelist
```

This latter solution creates links to the original files in a subdirectory, so you can run it multiple times without munging the original data. Also, it uses null separators in the file list so you can unambiguously distinguish names that have newlines or tabs or spaces in them.  It makes for a list that is not particularly human readable, but you can easily filter it through `tr` to make it pretty.

Comment: Is there any benefit of using `: $((i += 1))` over just `((i += 1))`?

Comment: @Socowi I don't think so, I just find the `(( i += 1))` a little weird and am more comfortable with `:`